# SQL Server 2012 INNER JOIN returning records that it shouldn't

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, inner-join

Using SQL Server 2012, and given the following code (modified to "hide" stuff)...

```
select T1.ID
    ,T2.F2
    ,T2.F3
    ,T2.F4
from (
         select distinct ID
         from A1
     ) T1
         inner join (
                        select ID
                            ,F2
                            ,F3
                            ,F4
                        from A2
                    ) T2 on T1.ID = T2.ID
where T2.F2 not in (V1,V2,V3,V4) and
    T2.F3 in (V5,V6,V7,V8)
```

...my goal is to get a list of items with matching IDs from the two tables, T1 and T2. All of the conditions are on the T2 table with the T1 table used to get only those records that match by ID. Fairly straight forward. HOWEVER... I'm getting records from T2 with no matching ID in T1. Even though the conditions are on T2, I still should expect T1 to be controlling which IDs are returned.

Values for the IDs:

```
T1: 3, 5, 6, 7, 10
T2: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
```

I expect to return:

```
T1: 3, 5, 6, 7, 10
T2: 3, 5, 6, 7, 10
```

But what I appear to be getting is:

```
T2: 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10
```

I even tried reintroducing the T1 unique IDs (as C1) after all of the other stuff...

```
select B1.ID
    ,B1.F2
    ,B1.F3
    ,B1.F4
from (
         select T1.ID
             ,T2.F2
             ,T2.F3
             ,T2.F4
         from (
                  select distinct ID
                  from A1
              ) T1
                  inner join (
                                 select ID
                                     ,F2
                                     ,F3
                                     ,F4
                                 from A2
                             ) T2 on T1.ID = T2.ID
         where T2.F2 not in (V1,V2,V3,V4) and
             T2.F3 in (V5,V6,V7,V8)
     ) B1
         inner join (
                        select distinct ID
                        from A1
                    ) C1 on B1.ID = C1.ID
```

...but no go. Same results.

It seems like it should be a straight forward inner join, yet it's acting more like a right join. Any thoughts or suggestions?

Comment: Add another `AND t1.id=t2.id` at the end.

Comment: It won't run. The way the query is constructed, the only IDs exposed for the join are from B1 and C1. T1 and T2 are within the B1 sub query, therefore not accessible on the outside. But I appreciate the quick reply!

Comment: Sorry. I meant to say I tried that, and it won't run. I try not to be so arrogant that I dismiss help out of hand!

Comment: Go with the correlated subquery `(select distinct ID
                  from A1 WHERE A1.ID=A2.ID)`

Answer (score 0):

I would use EXISTS in this case:

```
select T1.ID
  ,T2.F2
  ,T2.F3
  ,T2.F4
from A2 T2
where T2.F2 not in (V1,V2,V3,V4) 
  and T2.F3 in (V5,V6,V7,V8)
  and exists(
    select * from A1 T1 where T1.ID = T2.ID)
```

This is much simplere and will give you only those records in T2 that have a matching record in T1.